Missing or insufficient permissions
Currently I've set firebase for android and iOS in a KMM project.
I've added firebase sdk on both projects for the native part to configure them.
On the shared side, I'm using gitlive firebase sdk library, where I do a query to firestore database. So the logic to query data is SHARED
Here's the query:
    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    override fun invoke(): Flow<List<TicketUi>> = flow {
        val list =  Firebase.firestore
            .collection("users")
            .document(Firebase.auth.currentUser!!.uid)
            .collection("receipts")
            .snapshots
            .mapLatest {
                it.documents.map { doc ->
                    // Additional code converting the document to a Receipt
                }
            }

        // Collect the flow and emit the list
        list.collect { ticketUiList ->
            emit(ticketUiList)
        }
    }.catch { error ->
        Logger.e { "Error in GetAllTicketsUseCaseImpl.invoke(): ${error.cause} && message: ${error.message}" }
        emit(emptyList<TicketUi>())
    }

I've set up the emulator in order to test it on both platforms.
Android
It works perfectly, all good
iOS:

I've created a iOS project on Firebase
GoogleServices-Info.plist has been added to the project
I've added Firebase SDK to the project, that includes Auth & Firestore.
On AppDelegate I call the following code

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        // Firestore Configuration
        let settings = Firestore.firestore().settings
        settings.host = "127.0.0.1:8080"
        settings.cacheSettings = MemoryCacheSettings()
        settings.isSSLEnabled = false
        Firestore.firestore().settings = settings
        FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.debug)
        
        Auth.auth().useEmulator(withHost:"127.0.0.1", port:8081)
        let auth = Auth.auth()
        
         if auth.currentUser == nil {
             // Sign in anonymously
             auth.signInAnonymously { authResult, error in
                 if let error = error {
                     // Sign-in failed∂
                     print("signInAnonymously:failure \(error.localizedDescription)")
                 } else {
                     // Sign-in succeeded
                     print("signInAnonymously:success")
                     if let user = authResult?.user {
                         print("User: \(user.uid)")
                     }
                 }
             }
         } else {
             // Already signed in
             print("Already logged in: \(auth.currentUser?.uid ?? "No UID")")
         }

Cool. Time to query the data from firestore for that specific user. The following error shows up:

Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=7 "Missing or insufficient
permissions." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing or insufficient
permissions.


11.1.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Listen for query at users/9hYte9W9Sf1FlH6vMJdnVs0qPNLd/receipts failed: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Here is the rule for firestore emulator
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}

I don't understand what I could be missing, it must be something wrong on the iOS side as on Android I'm able to listen to the query without any issue and retrieve the data.
Is there anything that I might have missed? Or a way to obtain more data on what's exactly wrong?

Where is your code that performs the query and generates that error?  All you're showing now is what you do to sign in the user.  Please edit the question to show all relevant code.

@DougStevenson I've just edited it. I didn't post the query as I believe it's not the root cause since it's working as expected on Android. I thought there would be a misconfiguration from iOS side that is missing.

Found the root cause, it looks like it comes from the kotlin gitlive-firebase library.... Remove this.
Firebase.firestore.settings = firestoreSettings {
        }

Will probably ask in their github project why this happens.
